# Trigonometric Formulae Confusion

Tags: trigonometry

Confused among determining A & B in these trigonometric formulae..

$$\begin{align}
2 \sin A \cos B &= \sin (A+B)+ \sin (A-B)\\
2 \cos A \sin B &= \sin (A+B)- \sin (A-B)
\end{align}$$

I've got

$$ 2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \cos (nx) =
\sin \left(\frac{1}{2}+n\right)x + \sin \left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right)x $$

Which is correct from the first formula..

But in my book it is given as,

$$ 2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \cos (nx)= \sin \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)x - \sin \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)x $$

Which is also correct...

then Why such a difference? Is there any method to determine A & B in these formulas

Comment: The answer is staring you right in the face..

Comment: The sine is an *odd* function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO I guess the crucial point is to show that

$$\sin\left(\frac12-n\right)x~=~-\sin\left(n-\frac12\right)x$$

One could simply apply that the sine function is a odd function and therefore satisfies the relation

$$\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$$

Wich becomes the above equation with $x=n-\frac12$. Another way is to use the addition theorem for the sine function, which is given by

$$\sin(A-B)~=~\sin A\cos B-\sin B\cos A$$

So we get

$$\begin{align}
\sin\left(\frac12-n\right)x~&=~-\sin\left(n-\frac12\right)x\\
\sin\left(\frac{x}2\right)\cos\left(nx\right)
-\sin\left(nx\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}2\right)
~&=~-\left(\sin\left(nx\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}2\right)-
-\sin\left(\frac{x}2\right)\cos\left(nx\right)\right)\\
&=~\sin\left(\frac{x}2\right)\cos\left(nx\right)-
\sin\left(nx\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}2\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: this is what i was looking for...Thank You=

Answer (score 1):

Note you've left off "$\sin$" on the second term in your original problem statement (typo).

The two are the same formula. It's just because $\sin \theta = -\sin(-\theta)$ since $\sin$ is an odd function. In particular, since $a-b=-(b-a)$, you can write $\sin(a-b)=-\sin(-(b-a))$.

Comment: Ok...then the answer I've got is wrong?

Comment: $-\sin(n-1/2)x=\sin(1/2-n)x$

Comment: Ohh...thanks @MPW Got it

Answer (score 0):

Note via [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/p2xebsql5o) that:
$$\sin(x)\equiv-\sin(-x)$$

Hence:
$$\sin[(\frac12 -n)x]\equiv-\sin[(n-\frac12)x]$$

Comment: I know this...You didn't got my question

Comment: Fixed. Sorry...

Comment: Thank you..!!! Makes sense now